# Como evitar erro de cálculo no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma consulta que faz um calculo, mais o campo “a.totalcustoprodutos” aparece com valor zero em alguns momentos, então gera um erro de divisão por zero, é possível passar algum valor padrão? Tipo 1 caso tenha o valor zero?

```sql
select a.totalcustoprodutos, a.datanota, a.numeronota, a.cfop,
((a.totalnota / a.totalcustoprodutos) - 1.000) * 100 as TotalMargem   
from TB_C_VENDAS a      
where a.numeronota > 0 and a.tipooperacao = 'V'
```

Comment: E o correto assumir o valor de `a.totalnota` cheio se não tiver valor algum (0) em `a.totalcustoprodutos`? A lógica é esta que você quer, ou está só tentando resolver um problema causando outro?

Comment: Eu preciso do total totalcustoprodutos custo produto para encontra a média, não posso usar o totalnota. Agradeço!

Comment: Então as repostas dadas não faz o que você deseja, certo? O que deve ser feito então quando encontra um zero no `a.totalcustoprodutos`? Nada. não calcula? Gera erro? Pega outro valor? Usa uma fórmula completamente diferente?

Comment: Já postaram uma resposta que resolveu o problema. agradeço!

Comment: Se o que você comentou acima está certo esta resposta só resolve algumas situações. Mas não sou eu que terei prejuízo. Se realmente responde, o que você comentou está errado. Sem conhecer o real problema, eu duvido que isto solucione corretamente. E o problema pode estar em outro lugar. Talvez nem deveria ter o 0 lá. Mas aí já é especulação.

Comment: Você esta certo, não resolve em tudo, é preciso analisar o relatório depois mais é a única forma de não ter a mensagem de erro. Eu já identifiquei o porquê do total custo produtos = 0 mais eu preciso trazer todos os registros, então seria um jeito de evitar o erro inicial, depois do relatório então é possível analisar o porquê do custo zero. Agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o "Case" e substituir o "zero" por outro número:

Ex:

```
SELECT a.totalcustoprodutos,
       a.datanota,
       a.numeronota,
       a.cfop,
       ((a.totalnota / (CASE a.totalcustoprodutos WHEN 0 THEN 1 
                        ELSE a.totalcustoprodutos END)) - 1.000) * 100 AS TotalMargem,
FROM TB_C_VENDAS a
WHERE a.numeronota > 0
  AND a.tipooperacao = 'V'
```

Porém, será que apenas substituir 0 por 1 seria uma solução ou apenas um "jeitinho"?

Talvez seria legal identificar o porquê esse campo está igual a 0 e talvez adicionar um filtro no seu select para não trazer os registros que possuem na coluna totalcustoprodutos iguais a 0.

Comment: eu já identifiquei o porque do total custo produtos = 0 mais eu preciso trazer todos os registros, então seria um jeito de evitar o erro inicial, depois do relatório então é possível analisar o porque do custo zero. agradeço

Answer (score 3):

Tu pode fazer um "CASE". Veja:

```
select a.totalcustoprodutos, a.datanota, a.numeronota,a.cfop, ((a.totalnota / (CASE WHEN a.totalcustoprodutos > 0 THEN a.totalcustoprodutos ELSE 1 END)) - 1.000) * 100 as TotalMargem 
from TB_C_VENDAS a
where a.numeronota > 0 and a.tipooperacao = 'V'
```

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

SELECT a.totalcustoprodutos,
       a.datanota,
       a.numeronota,
       a.cfop,
       ((a.totalnota / NULLIF(isnull(a.totalcustoprodutos,0))) - 1.000) * 100 AS TotalMargem,
FROM TB_C_VENDAS a
WHERE a.numeronota > 0
  AND a.tipooperacao = 'V'

assim fica bem mais simples
a funcao NULLIF retona null caso o a.totalcustoprodutos seja 0
como a.totalcustoprodutos tambem pode ser null, forcamos o 0 com a isnull
um valor dividido por null retorna null e nao da erro.
um valor dividido por 0 da erro.